# Disable Usb Ports in rooted Android device

Tags: android, usb, libusb, usb-otg, rooted-device

I want to disable usb ports in my rooted android device, When I run below code it returns result is true but usb ports is still active, I want to disable usb ports When I click disable button and then When I click enable button, enable usb ports how can I do this?

```
disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        String[] command = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level", };
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define in drivers, and after echo define name of the usb like below code.

```
String command = "echo 'usb1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind";
```